# Captain Sisay and flip legendarys from Kamigawa?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Captain Sisay](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Captain%20Sisay) search for a card that is only legendary when it is flipped? ex. [Bushi Tenderfoot](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bushi%20Tenderfoot)

Comment: I don't know MTG but it seems like, to be a duplicate, the former question should be reworded to something like "For the purposes of selecting or finding a card, can I consider a card to have the attribute that it would have when flipped?" It seems much easier for someone wondering about this case or about flipped cards to find the answer to their question which I would think would be the main benefit of the question that is the duplicate.

Comment: @Joey Done. Keep in mind that just because two questions use different *examples*, they may still be asking the same *question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, Captain Sisay can't find cards that are only legendary when flipped**

From the Comprehensive rules:

> 709.2. In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield before the permanent flips, a flip card has only the normal characteristics of the card. Once a permanent is flipped, its normal name, text box, type line, power, and toughness don’t apply and the alternative versions of those characteristics apply instead.
>
> *Example: Akki Lavarunner is a nonlegendary creature that flips into a legendary creature named Tok-Tok, Volcano Born. An effect that says “Search your library for a legendary card” can’t find this flip card. An effect that says “Legendary creatures get +2/+2” doesn’t affect Akki Lavarunner, but it does affect Tok-Tok.*

Comment: I suppose that logically explains why they can't be your commander either.